# Giving command line .exe administrators privileges

Tags: windows, wget

I downloaded wget for windows.

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

I ran this to recieve some web pages but it seems permission was denied for writing or something.

How do you run command line apps with administrator priveleges?

Thanks

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: Sorry Windows 7 Updated Main OP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run cmd with administrator privileges (right click and run as administrator).

Comment: If you go under wget's properties, you can specify that it runs with admin privs everytime.

Answer (score 1):

In cmd you can use this:

> runas /profile /user:Administrator **program name**